# Can I use Karabiner Elements as a hotkey to swap function keys?

Tags: karabiner

MacOS doesn't come with a default hotkey for swapping the function keys.

Is there some way to set up a Karabiner Elements hotkey to do it?

For clarification, the setting in the below image is the setting I'm referring to.

[image]

Comment: Your question and image aren't clear.  What do you want to swap the Fn keys *with*?

Comment: @Allan I want a hotkey that mimics the behavior of the toggle in the image I posted

Comment: So, you want to ***toggle the use Fn keys as standard on/off***?  This is not a Karabiner function.  You might be able to fo this with AppleScript. I am, however, not understanding how pressing the `Fn` button is not working for you.  What is the use case?

Comment: @Allan I am looking for the same feature, as far as I know Karabiner does not provide it.
My use case is that some applications / tasks require intensive use of function keys (e.g. debugging on VSCode or Chrome), and some others don't. Having to always press+hold the "fn" key in order to activate function keys is very inconvenient.

Comment: @LuisCrespo Yes. On my windows laptop (XPS 13) I simple press Fn+Esc to swap the function keys. I was surprised when this function is not easily available on the Mac

Comment: @Allan You can toggle the System setting with AppleScript and then invoke that system setting with a hotkey. But then if you are using Karabiner, the setting in Karabiner overrides the system setting, which gets ignored. In summary, if you use Karabiner, you are not able to toggle that setting with AppleScript.